# Set JSON as default into 'View Results Tree'

Tags: jmeter

I'm trying to set JSON as 'View Results Tree' default rendered.

[image]

I can find way to set: order of the renders, but is it possible to set JSON as default?

What ever I set, text is always set as default render.

*The config file that i used is: `jmeter.proporties`

*JMeter version: 5.11

*`view.results.tree.renderers_order=.RenderAsJSON,.RenderAsText,.RenderAsRegexp,.RenderAsBoundaryExtractor,.RenderAsCssJQuery,.RenderAsXPath,org.apache.jmeter.extractor.json.render.RenderAsJsonRenderer,.RenderAsHTML,.RenderAsHTMLFormatted,.RenderAsHTMLWithEmbedded,.RenderAsDocument,.RenderAsXML`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's set to have Text as default render option in JMeter's [code](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/master/src/components/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/visualizers/ViewResultsFullVisualizer.java#L493):

> ```
> nodesModel.setSelectedItem(textObject); // preset to "Text" option
> ```

You can open a [new enhancement](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi) in order to add such support

Answer (score 1):

Changing the order using view.results.tree.renderers_order works for me using JMeter 5.4.3

Answer (score 0):

You can execute the following steps:

```
cd /path/to/jmeter/bin
vi jmeter.properties
# Find the view.results.tree.renderers_order setting
# Put the .RenderAsJSON as the first one
```

Then you open jmeter, the json type is the default now.